# Hotspot Facebook mesenger

Tags: facebook, messenger

We are providing to our customers free wifi service. They are logging in with facebook. Now we want to create a bot related to our fb page and messaging with our customers to get some feedback. I ve found some articles about messenger bots but i couldnt find how to start this conversation. Is there any way to start conversation with our customers? I mean we want to send first message

Thank you in advance

Comment: No there is not, if there was we’d all get spammed all the time. The user has to initiate the conversation, there’s several ways how you can try and get them to do that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery

Comment: Thank you, but there is no way to reach them? maybe post to wall? How i can use their data locally?

Comment: No, of course you can not post to their wall - again, if possible, any spammer out there would do this. And what data do you want to use locally, what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: but we have their approval. Just i wonder how can i reach them while they are online under our hotspot.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if you have “their approval” ... you don’t have Facebook’s, to contact users whenever you like. [Facebook Wi-Fi](https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi) at most allows to demand users check-in at a place to use the service; so there is no reason why you should be allowed to do any more.

Comment: So can i use this data for paid facebook ads? I mean just want to show our ads to this customers?

Comment: _What_ data? And no, you can not target specific users with adds directly.

Comment: Please don't contact users via facebook. Think of this from the users point of view: Some unknown entity is contacting you about the wifi in some place you have been to recently. Don't you think this is creepy? When receiving such a message, I would immediately mark the sending user as spam. And depending on the message I would try to find out how to flag the application.

Comment: If you want the feedback, show a link to your feedback survey.